# How can I fix this deprecation warning? "Default & named imports from CSS files are deprecated"

Tags: css, reactjs

Message:

> Default and named imports from CSS files are deprecated. Use the ?inline query instead

This has just occurred recently in my React project, and I'm wondering how I can use an inline query. I've looked online and can't find anything.

Comment: *What* issued the deprecation warning? At run-time in the browser (JavaScript log)? What did you do? *Where* did it appear? What is the environment for the React project? [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)? What is the build system?

Comment: I faced with similar issue, when one of my dependencies imports external CSS from another dependency as `import '@company/styles/style.css'` - https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/12101

You can read more about this warning here https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/10762.

Comment: Thanks so much the information was really helpful. I fixed the error but it's good to know as to why it happened

Comment: @TheHollyRoller If you fixed the error, would you be so kind to post the solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using CSS modules and failing that you could delete the node modules and re-install them.

Also, how I fixed this issue was creating a new CSS file and re-installing the necessary dependencies. If that still does not work then you could always try with a fresh project folder if you're in a prototyping phase.

Also on the GitHub discussion for this issues it was recommended to use this
syntax when with your CSS imports

```
import stuff from './global.css?inline'
```

Answer (score 4):

You must import not plain scss. Add 'module' in name your scss file, like "style.module.scss". After that "import myDiv (or any name) from './style.module.scss'"

Comment: If you want to use named css modules then this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

import "./app.modules.css";

```
<div className="app">
```

just import without name and pass the class like in html.